# Insert space between each punctuation mark

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string and before and after each punctuation mark I want to insert a space like so

`aaa , bbb . Hello ! here .` I tried using the `replaceAll` method, I wanted something similar to:

`String result = myStr.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "\s\\p{Punct}\s");`

but since the second argument has to be a String, this does not work. Is there any way this could be accomplished using a regular expression ? Or I have to capture the punctuation mark separately and then replace it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backreferences and literals in the replacement:

```
String result = myStr.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " $0 ");
```

Or (if you want to wrap a sequence of punctuation symbols):

```
String result = myStr.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " $0 ");
```

See the [demo](https://ideone.com/4IbOUk) below:

```
String s = "aaa,fgh!edrf.";
String result = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " $0 ");
System.out.println(result); // => aaa , fgh ! edrf . 
System.out.println("aaa,,,fgh!!!edrf???".replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " $0 "));
// => aaa ,,, fgh !!! edrf ???
```

Comment: Very close, but OP wants space before and after punctuation. hint. `aaa , , , `

Comment: @Saleem: `" $0 "` inserts spaces around the punctuation symbol(s) matched. `"\\p{Punct}"` matches each symbol individually, and `"\\p{Punct}+"` matches consecutive chunks of punctuation symbols.

Comment: I'm actually looking at `// => aaa ,,, fgh !!! edrf ??? ` I see it's spacing out groups but individual punctuation. hope you got point.

Comment: @Saleem: Did you use `myStr.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " $0 ");`? I guess not.

Comment: @Saleem: I have 2 alternatives depending on what OP really needs.

Comment: ahh, got it. I'd suggest to clarify it little bit. otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

You could match each punctuation mark, and replace with " $0 ":

```
String input = "aaa,bbb.Hello!here.";
String result = input.replaceAll("[.!?\\-]", " $0 ");
System.out.println (result);
```

Output:

```
aaa , bbb . Hello ! here .
```